# Passing a listed range of an attribute to its own object (Python)

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to create a class of objects which print "BOO!" a certain number of times, based on the current (particular) object's scariness level. I've created the attribute scariness, but I want to create a function which takes a range from 0 to that scariness level, then takes that range as a list, then prints "BOO!" for every element in that list. I've tried it two ways, here is my code:

Version 1:

```
class Ghost:  
    def __init__(self, name, scariness, scarylist):  
        self.name = name  
        self.scariness = scariness  
        self.scarylist = list(range[scariness])  
    def scare_human(self):  
        for i in scarylist:  
            print('BOO!')

steve = Ghost("Steve", 1000, scarylist)
```

When I execute the cell beginning with `scarylist = list[range(1000)]` in my IDE (Jupyter Notebook if it matters) I get the error, "'Type' object is not subscriptable." I'm guessing there are a couple things wrong with this version.

Version 2:

```
class Ghost:  
    scarylist = list(range[scariness])  
    def scare_human(self):  
        for i in scarylist:  
            print('BOO!')  

steve = Ghost()  
steve.name = "Steve"  
steve.scariness = 1000  
steve.hungriness = 10
```

The trouble with this version is that I have to define the attributes of the class *before* I want to call them as variables of a function of the class. I can't do this if I use this kind of definition of the class.

Comment: In your first implementation, replace every `[ ... ]` with a `( ... )`

Comment: what's the point of the `scarylist` argument in V1 constructor if you're just overwriting it with a derivation of `scariness`?

Comment: You are trying to use `range` with scare brackets, that's what the error is telling you, that won't work, you have to *call* it. So `range(scariness)`. Note, there's no good reason to make it into a list, just keep it as a range object. so just use `self.scarylist = range(scariness)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a function which takes a range from 0 to that scariness level, then takes that range as a list, then prints "BOO!" for every element in that list.

It's possible I'm missing something, but I'm not sure why you need to create a range out of `scariness: int` in order to print `BOO!` `scariness` number of times.

Here's my version of `Ghost` that does what I think you were aiming for:

```py
>>> class Ghost:  
    def __init__(self, name, scariness):  
        self.name = name  
        self.scariness = scariness 
    def scare_human(self):  
        for _ in range(self.scariness):  
            print('BOO!')


>>> steve = Ghost("Steve", 10)
>>> steve.scare_human()
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
BOO!
```